# ASP.net deny access to folder doesn't work on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I want to deny access to the folder with images on my site.

I use the following section in `web.config` for this:

```
<location path="images/catalog">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

It works fine locally but doesn't work on the server (IIS7). Any ideas?

May be you have another solution how to deny access to images in specific folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS7 Forms Authentication Doesn't Deny Image Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447273/iis7-forms-authentication-doesnt-deny-image-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

I have added this section to `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />

    <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
    <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The reason - IIS7 for some reason ignores forms authentication.

In these questions you can find the cause and solution:

1. [asp.net - runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = “true” killing windows authentication in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030138/runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-killing-windows-authentication-in-ii)
2. [IIS7 Forms Authentication Doesn't Deny Image Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447273/iis7-forms-authentication-doesnt-deny-image-access?rq=1)